# How do I configure Microsoft Remote Desktop to remote into my PC from my Android tablet?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, remote-desktop, android

I have installed the Microsoft remote desktop app from the Google play store, and ran it while I was at home, and it worked fine; I have a wireless cable modem router, so I added and configured a gateway to my modems IP address, and setup a remote desktop connection to the local IP that my system had on the router. I made sure that the system was configured to accept remote connections, and tried the remote connection, and it worked! At least, as long as my tablet was connected to my wireless cable modem. As soon as I tried to connect from a different hotspot, the connection failed.

How am I supposed to configure this app to remote in from any hotspot? It's useless to me if I can only remote in while I'm at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your home network is behind NAT, you need to configure your tablet to access hosts behind NAT.

Here is a guide which is related to your question:

[Allow Remote Desktop connections from outside your home network](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network)

Comment: Okay; I've followed those directions, but the connection still fails; I get 'Connection Refused'.

Comment: Ok - the IP I was entering was wrong; so, user error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use VNC viewer. Here is a [guide](http://www.thegeekbyte.com/windows/1185/remote-control-pc-anywhere/) on setting up a VNC server.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: That page now goes to a 404.